# Curl verify certificate improperly on OSX

Tags: curl, https

### Problem:

I used curl to launch a https request on my MacOs:

[image]

but witing wget:

```
wget -v https://m2.mogucdn.com/p1/160725/upload_ifrtenzsgq4gcodghezdambqhayde_217x278.jpg
--2016-10-14 17:57:33-- https://m2.mogucdn.com/p1/160725/upload_ifrtenzsgq4gcodghezdambqhayde_217x278.jpg
Resolving m2.mogucdn.com... 183.134.101.194, 183.158.35.59, 183.158.35.57, ...
Connecting to m2.mogucdn.com|183.134.101.194|:443... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify m2.mogucdn.com's certificate, issued by 'CN=Symantec Class 3 Secure Server CA - G4,OU=Symantec Trust Network,O=Symantec Corporation,C=US':
Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
To connect to m2.mogucdn.com insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
```

As a comparison，using curl on CentOS7：

```
curl -vo /dev/null https://m2.mogucdn.com/p1/160725/upload_ifrtenzsgq4gcodghezdambqhayde_217x278.jpg
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   0*   Trying 183.158.35.60...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to m2.mogucdn.com (183.158.35.60) port 443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
CApath: none
* Server certificate:
*       subject: CN=*.mogucdn.com,OU=RD,O=Hangzhou Juangua Network      Limited,L=Hangzhou,ST=Zhejiang,C=CN
*       start date: Mar 02 00:00:00 2015 GMT
*       expire date: Mar 01 23:59:59 2018 GMT
*       common name: *.mogucdn.com
*       issuer: CN=Symantec Class 3 Secure Server CA - G4,OU=Symantec Trust Network,O=Symantec Corporation,C=US
* NSS error -8179 (SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER)
* Peer's Certificate issuer is not recognized.
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 1
* stopped the pause stream!
0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
* Closing connection 0
curl: (60) Peer's Certificate issuer is not recognized.
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
the -k (or --insecure) option.
```

What is the difference between curl on OSX and curl on centos

Comment: Why do you claim there is a difference? I cannot see anything comparing the two versions in your question.

Comment: In fact, this certificate chain is invalid, it's ok if you using curl on linux, but if you using curl on osx, you can get the http response successfully